# How can I count the size of downloads from my users?

Tags: php, download, bandwidth

Is this possible to calculate size of downloads from users?
for example, I have a music with size 10MB and the download link is resume-able.
If my user get 50%, can I know that the size of his download?

Its better to be done with PHP.

Comment: I suspect the only way to do this will be to parse your web server logs. Although maybe some server will return this sort of status to your PHP/CGI/whatever script after the HTTP request has completed (or prematurely terminated).

Answer (score 0):

To know the size of the actual download, you need to name the method/process which delivers the downloads. That process could know.

For example, if you serve the files via your server, you can normally configure the server logs to store that information. You can then parse log-files to obtain the download size(s).

> Its better to be done with PHP.

However you like to do it, I can not say it's better to be done with PHP, but if it's better for you, then do it with PHP.